# How to - Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to create an application that does following:

1. Get current location (cellid, mnc, mmc, lac, lat, lng)
2. Read/Write/Delete/Intercept SMS, CallLog, Contact, Calendar, Files, Notes
3. Get Installed Application List
4. Using SQLite
5. Email & VPN Configuration
6. Ability to enable/disable bluetooth, GPRS, wi-fi
7. Voice Recording
8. Encryption
9. Control Phone Profile
10. JSON
11. File System notifications

Which of above is supported by Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MOSTLY YES - Get current location (cellid, mnc, mmc, lac, lat, lng)

MOSTLY NO - Read/Write/Delete/Intercept SMS, CallLog, Contact, Calendar, Files, Notes

NO - Get Installed Application List

YES - Using SQLite

NO - Email & VPN Configuration

MOSTLY NO - Ability to enable/disable bluetooth, GPRS, wi-fi

YES - Voice Recording

YES - Encryption

MOSTLY NO - Control Phone Profile

YES - JSON

MOSTLY NO - File System notifications

Comment: This answer gives you the basics - beyond this, I recommend you download the tools and have a look yourself - http://create.msdn.com